# Convert .caf to .mp3 on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, mp3, core-audio

is there a way to convert my recorded .caf files to .mp3 using the
iPhone SDK / Core Audio, something else?

I've been looking around for a while, but all I've found was a command line uitility (which
isn't allowed to run on the iPhone).

Regards

Comment: Your .caf file is probably actually a .wav or .aiff file (rename it and see), and people might respond to the question better if you say that instead. However, I'm not sure the iPhone can be used to convert audio.

Comment: To convert audio easily, I mean. It CAN be done, but I'm not sure if there are any APIs to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the iPhone shouldn't really be used for processor intensive things such as audio conversion, have you thought about transferring those files to your computer and running the conversion there using the command line tool you mentioned? I'm sure you could automate it pretty easily.

Comment: Yes, I could do that easily on my server. The problem is that .caf files are very inefficient regarding the file size (about 5 MB/minute). I don't want to bother my users with vast traffic for short audio clips.