# how to convert (aiff) files to any format that runs on windows OS(.asf, .asx, .avi, .wav, .wax, .wma, .wm, .wmv )?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mp3, audiotoolbox, caf

i'm working on  an iPhone project and wants to save mp3 files instead of car, i wrote this code to save record files in .caf extensions:

```
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    NSString *recorderFilePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf",  DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,fileName];
```

i tried this:

```
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
 NSString *recorderFilePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,fileName];
```

but it didn't save in mp3 format! is it available in objective c or there's any third party code that makes that, i see that method in AudioToolbox.framework:

```
OSStatus AudioConverterConvertBuffer (
AudioConverterRef  inAudioConverter,
UInt32             inInputDataSize,

const void         *inInputData,

UInt32             *ioOutputDataSize,

void               *outOutputData

);
```

any help is welcomed,thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert .caf to .mp3 on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859151/convert-caf-to-mp3-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source project [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) . The challenge would be making it work for iphone.   [This](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/) would give a direction towards cross compiling for ios.

Also note it is GPL.